# error while installing npm canvas

Tags: canvas, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to use this repository:
https://github.com/lokesh/color-thief/

While trying to use it I realized I needed to install the **npm canvas** package.
I went to https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas, but that didn't work so I went to the Installation Wiki at https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/wiki/Installation---Windows.

I've installed Python 2.7, the Express Visual Studio package, and GTK 2 as written in the instructions. I also ran `npm install -g node-gyp` in the cmd and it seemed to go through with no errors.

When after all this I try to run `npm install canvas` I still get errors. I'm attaching the npm-debug.log here:

http://www.filedropper.com/npm-debug

Comment: Update: I've tried to figure it out. I managed to `npm install canvas`, [sadly the tab where I found the solution is gone but it involved `npm config set msvs_version 2015 --global`].
In any case, right now I'm trying to `npm install color-thief` which should work, but i'm getting a bunch of 
`\stdio.h(1925): warning C4005: 'snprintf': macro
 redefinition`

as well as 

`\stdio.h(1927): fatal error C1189: #error:  Macr
o definition of snprintf conflicts with Standard Library function declaration`


The cmd shows it is probably a `node-gyp rebuild` problem..
Any ideas... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poking around with the library, I have found the following information:

1. you need to use Image objects to load the dominant color.
2. you don't really need NodeJS here, it works straight on the website
3. you can use it with only 5 LOC.

Here is the simplest code snippet :

```
var image = new Image; //create the image object
image.onload = function () {
    var colorThief = new ColorThief(); //create the lib's object
    var dominantColor = colorThief.getColor(image); //get the dominant color
}
image.src = "source/to/image";
```

- The dominant color `getColor()` function will return a RGB array (`[R, G, B])`

you can look at the `color-thief.js` file to see all the function - this file is well documented.